# Get both data and column name from sql table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I know how to get the column names from a table

```
SELECT Column_name
from Information_schema.columns 
where Table_name like 'summary'
```

And I know how to get the data like below

```
SELECT * FROM [summary] where Id='12345";
```

but how do I combine these so that I **atleast** get column names of a table even if there is no data?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT__________________________________________________________**

```
table  
id    name
123    test
12345   test2
```

in the above example after I have run this combined query I expect the result to be

```
id  12345
name test2
```

but if I run the query with an id like "hello"

then the result shall be

```
id
name
```

Comment: Can you provide some sample data and what you are looking for?  For one thing, you have typing problems, the way you have described the problem -- column names are necessarily strings.  Column values are not.

Comment: Precisley, column values are mandatory since there can be the case where there is not data for a specified id, but in anycase I would like the column names.

Comment: If you first get your `Column_name`s and then build `SELECT columnName1, columnName2, ... FROM ...` you would know the columns you are returning. But it really depends where, how and why you are trying to do this!

Comment: @Captain:- Correct me if I am wrong but `select *` will all give the same result ;)

Comment: @R.T. same result indeed - but if this is being done through an own-built application, you then have the necessary column information even if the select gives you nothing... that was my thinking :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IF you want to column names of a table when there is no data then you used like this

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM [summary] where Id='12345') 
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM [summary] where Id='12345'
END  
ELSE
BEGIN
    SELECT Column_name
    FROM   Information_schema.columns 
    WHERE  Table_name like 'summary'
END
```

Comment: @Anders . . . Interesting that you accepted this answer.  The `then` query returns one row with multiple columns and the `else` returns one column with multiple rows.

Answer (score 0):

First Query Use exact column name to find

```
SELECT Column_name
FROM Information_schema.columns 
WHERE Table_name LIKE 'Columns'
```

Second query:

```
SELECT * FROM [summary] WHERE Id='12345";
```

Union all the both queries like below:

```
SELECT Column_name
FROM Information_schema.columns 
WHERE Table_name LIKE 'IND'

UNION ALL

SELECT * FROM [summary] WHERE Id='12345";
```

Answer (score 0):

What columns are returned when you execute a t-sql Select statement depends on your Select statement, data inside the columns does not affect the number columns being returned from your select statement.

```
SELECT Column1 , Column2 , Column3  --<-- COlumn names 
FROM Table_Name
```

In above query regardless of what data is present in columns Column1 , Column2 and Column3 the query will return all three columns.

So your assumption that query should return a column even if no data exists is wrong.

You can either Explicitly use the column names in your select statement that you want to return like in above mentioned statement, or you can make use of `*` instead of using column names which will return all the column present in that table regardless of if there is any data stored in them or not.

```
SELECT *
FROM Table_Name
```

Answer (score 0):

I think using simple `CASE` here would be enough:

```
SELECT 
   case when id is null then '' else id end ,  
   case when name is null then '' else name end
FROM [summary] where Id='hello';
```